# Creating a table in a database on Cloudcontrol

Tags: mysql, cloudcontrol

On Cloudcontrol, I have added the *MySQLs Add-on* to my application. I can connect to the DB from my code (i am using the *Yii* framework). Now I want to create tables in my database, how can I achieve that? The credentials of the database are all known.

So far, I could use *cctrlapp* to connect to my app:

```
cctrlapp myapp/default run bash
```

Then I tried:

```
mysql
```

the server said: *command not found*.

From bash, I tried to *SSH* to *MYSQLS_HOSTNAME* providing *MYSQLS_USERNAME*, no result.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/add-on-documentation/mysqls#external-access:

Download the [certificate file](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem) to your local machine.
Connect to the database using an SSL encrypted connection.
The following example uses the MySQL command line tool.

$ mysql -u MYSQLS_USERNAME -p --host=MYSQLS_HOSTNAME --ssl-ca=PATH_TO_CERTIFICATE/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem